# Run npm install with other commands for project

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to run a the command “npm install”  which is under the hood 
Other command , like postinstall  etc. I know that you can run `npm run <scriptName>` but 
Not sure how to run some command from the script section (of the package.json)during the `npm install` command.

I try to read about it, not find any hint...
https://michael-kuehnel.de/tooling/2018/03/22/helpers-and-tips-for-npm-run-scripts.html

Comment: what exactly is you want ? , to run some command from `package.json` scripts section you run `npm run 'command name'`

Comment: @siddhantsankhe - that when I run the command `npm install` it will run additional command before or after but just when using the command `npm install` is it possible ?

Comment: well you could use pipes for chaining the commands ,`npm install debug | npm run dev` like this

Comment: that is link to you own question

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node pre.js",
    "postinstall": "node post.js"
  }
```

You can have a pre and post term before any command which will execute before and after the command. It can be any command

For Example:-

```
  "scripts": {
    "check1": "node run.js",
    "precheck1": "node pre.js",
    "postcheck1": "node post.js"
  }
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Does it mean that this command will run just when I run `npm install` ?

Comment: preinstall will run before and postinstall will run after npm install

Comment: Likewise pre and post can be added to any script